Yet another Product of sums expressed as sums of products
With respect to this question Product of sums as sum of products) and the answer by @pjs36 , I was thinking of a more general type of product of sums where the number of summands in each sum could be possibly different .
Thus,  I want to express $\Pi_{i=1}^n\big( \sum_{j=1}^{m_i} a_{ij}\big) $ as sums of products where all indices and range are from natural numbers .
Each summand term will include product of $n$ terms . With respect to the usual notation $[n]=\{1,2,3,...,n\} $, I want a function
$f : [n] \rightarrow \cup _{i=1}^n [m_i] $
Where $ f(i) \in [m_i]$ ,for each  $ 1\le i\le n  $
Let the collection of all such functions be $S$
So that for each $1\le i\le n$ , the terms in the sum look like
$\Pi_{i=1}^n a_{i , f(i)}   $ and thus my required expression  would be
$\sum _{f\in S} \Pi _{i=1}^n a_{i,f(i)}     $ ?
Apologies if my writing seems confusing as I am myself unsure how to express it more
intelligibly. I just want to know if I am thinking correctly and if not , what's the correct way

When expanding the product into a series, each summand has $n$ factors $a_{i,s(i)}$ with $1\leq i\leq n$ and $s_i$ being an element from the cartesian product $[m_1]\times[m_2]\times\cdots\times[m_n]$. We can therefore write
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\prod_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{m_i}a_{i,j}
=\sum_{(s_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}\in [m_1]\times \cdots\times [m_n]}\prod_{j=1}^n a_{i,s_i}}
\end{align*}
Here $s$ is a function from $[n]$ onto $[m_1]\times\cdots\times[m_n]$.
